# Css Changes of a file after adding another file

Tags: css

I have one file menubar.php and one file Homepage.php 
When i add the menubar.php  to Homepage.php  the Overall Css of file Homepage.php changes.
(Mostly Changes occurs in padding and margins and div height and width and all div becomes scattered )

I have tried to find the error but fialed.
Any one will help me that what kind of error is that.

Answer (score 0):

check CSS using firebug tool. your original CSS may be being overidden by the existing CSS in the file being included.

Comment: I used much different selectors for both files. Now going to check it with firebug tool.  Thanks